# White Blank Page when Updating and Publishing Page/Post

Tags: posts, pages, errors, troubleshooting

I have a serious problem here, every time I publish and update a page/post it displays a white blank page.. [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wBFR.jpg) I don't know how to fix it.. is there anyone that can help me? Thanks :)

Comment: Please add [debug information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) to your question to make answers possible.

Comment: I like your screenshot. So clean, minimal. Lovely.

Comment: Check files on your currenly active theme. check whether any php file have spaces either before/after the php tag

Comment: I had same problem. I updated my chrome browser and problem resolved. Now I can edit and create new posts and pages.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely a plugin. Disable them, and see if that fixes it. If it does, enable one by one, until you find the culprit.

If it's not a plugin (and even if it is), you can try to increase the memory allocated for PHP. Add this to your config.php:

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');
```

You can read more about the memory limit here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Increasing_memory_allocated_to_PHP

Comment: ok sir, thanks, I already fixed it.. it was on the theme's funtions.php .

Answer (score 1):

```
There will be many reasons for blank page, you have not mention version for wp, php etc.
To solve wordpress blank page issue follow the steps
```

1. disable all plugin and try (if there is an error in plugins then enable 1 by 1)
2. switch to default theme and try (if there is an error in theme)
3. rename .htaccess and param-link to default (page/post id)